# CSS translate position with percentage causing font elements to blur

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the technique for centering an element in the screen like this:

```
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
z-index: 99999;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
min-width: 350px;
max-width: 500px;
padding: 20px 30px 35px;
```

It is causing the text inside of the box to be blurry. I've searched for a solution and although some people recomment using -webkit-font-smoothing, it didn't resolve the issue with any of it's possible values.

Edit:

Without translate property:

[image]

With Translate property:

[image]

How can I stop this from happening? (I'm on chrome btw)

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: I keep getting this as well when using http://iscrolljs.com/ library. I assume it's the same problem and I suspect a chrome bug.

Comment: what font are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `preserve-3d`on the parent element. When elements are translated via a percentage they can be placed on a half pixel which doesn't always render correctly.

```
.parent-element {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but won't have any effect

Comment: @raphadko Please post your full HTML and CSS.